# request toolbelt upload a huge file

Tags: python, django, python-requests, bottle

Im trying to upload a huge file using request toolbelt. The file is collected from a HTML form using Python Bottle framework

```
uploadfile = request.files.get('File Upload')

payload = MultipartEncoder({uploadfile.filename:uploadfile.file.read()})

r = requests.post(url,
                files=payload,auth=(username,password))
```

Error

```
TypeError: 'MultipartEncoder' object is not iterable
```

Question:
1. How to send the collected file object?

Answer (score 1):

When using a `MultipartEncoder`, I send the information as the post `data` attribute as seen in their examples:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-toolbelt/0.3.0

Here is an example script I would use:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests

uploadfile = open("./example_upload.dat", "r")
payload = MultipartEncoder({uploadfile.name: uploadfile})

r = requests.post(
    "http://example.com",
    data=payload,
    auth=("exampleuser","examplepassword"),
    headers={"Content-Type": payload.content_type})
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with what Django returns as `uploadfile` here, but it seems like the question uses `uploadfile.file.read()` so perhaps it should be `{uploadfile.filename: uploadfile.file}`